# Images lose transparency with imagick?

Tags: php, image, imagick

This is my first time fiddling with imagick/dynamic images. All of my images used for the layers to build an image are transparent PNG files. However, when compressing the images into one image via imagick for some reason the transparency is lost, resulting in a white background and white wherever it should be transparent. Is this a normal problem, and is there a way to fix it? Here is my section right after I list the images to use;

```
$composed_image = new \Imagick($images);
$image = $composed_image->mergeImageLayers(\Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);
$image->setImageFormat('png');
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image->getImageBlob();
```

Comment: Try this before flattening... `setImageBackgroundColor('#FFFFFF');`

Comment: There is a package called [pslayers](https://github.com/darrynten/pslayers) that we use it in production on a few of our apps to handle things like this. Disclaimer: am author of package.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that I needed to go through and apply this to every image layer:
`$composed_image->setImageBackgroundColor('transparent'); $composed_image->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_REMOVE);`